# How can I convert multiple arrays into one single variable string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, concatenation

I have three arrays like this:

```
$a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"];
$b = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"];
$c = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"];
```

I am looking for a way to convert the three arrays into a **single string** and save it in a variable like this:

```
$abc = "a1 , b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4, a5, b5, c5";
```

I have tried imploding, but it maybe my method is not so good. I am using PHP 5.4.

### Note

Please note that the following code can be used, but I am not willing to use it.
It works for me, but I feel like reinventing the wheel:

```
array_push($abc, $a);
array_push($abc, ",");
array_push($abc, $b);
array_push($abc, ",");
array_push($abc, $c);

if ($key < (sizeof($a)-1)){
    array_push($abc, ",");
}
```

Comment: have you tried `array_merge($array1, $array2);`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php. On the right side there a few other posibilities

Comment: I find it a little funny that everyone rushed to submit that answer

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: The selected answer does exactly that I was looking for. The code that I had made involved using foreach(). I was pushing three arrays sequentially (i.e. [a1, b2, c1, a2, b2].....). Afterwards, I was going to either use implode or use another foreach() to add abc[] into a single string. Either way, it would have been chaotic compared to the selected answer. The selected answer on the other hand does this in just three lines of code. As David Thomas said in the comment of selected answer, "I forget, sometimes, that php can be quite beautiful."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all 3 arrays at once with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). So first you transpose your array into this format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a1, b1, c1
    [1] => a2, b2, c2
    [2] => a3, b3, c3
    [3] => a4, b4, c4
    [4] => a5, b5, c5
)
```

Then you [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) this array into your expected string.

Code:

```
<?php

    $a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"];
    $b = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"];
    $c = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"];

    $result = implode(", ", array_map(function($v1, $v2, $v3){
        return "$v1, $v2, $v3";
    }, $a, $b, $c));

    echo $result;

?>
```

output:

```
a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4, a5, b5, c5
```

Comment: Can you believe that I was about to post the same solution? :°D 25 second late

Comment: Nicely done, I forget, sometimes, that php *can* be quite beautiful.

Comment: Wow! This did precisely what I wanted. This technique replaced my 15 lines  of code with just three!
Thanks.